# logstash input file configuration -- fetch input file from different docker

Tags: docker, logstash

I am using docker . My log files are in one docker and logstash running in another docker .

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/folder/file.log"
    start_position => "end"
    id => "file"
  }
}
```

how can i tell fetch input file from docker1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways you can achieve that. First just use `volumes` to share data between several containers. One container will write data into volume, another one - read.

Example:

```
docker volume create foo
docker run -d --name writer -v foo:/var/log <image-name>
docker run -d --name logstash -v foo:/folder:ro <logstash-blah-blag>
```

note I've mount volume in readonly `ro` mode for logstash because it needs only read access. In this configuration all data, which container 1 writes into `/var/log` folder will be visible as `/folder` in logstash.

Second approach is IMHO better - use `tcp/ip` instead of volumes. You need to setup [FileBeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat) (another tool from Elastic) in container 1 and configure it to send data into logstash. Then just use `beats` input in logstash instead of `file`. Example:

```
input {
    beats {
        port => 5400
    }
}
```